# Orientation of cones and transitive closures of a dmplex in Petsc

Tags: petsc

From the Petsc manual pages, I fail to understand what the orientations of cones and transitive closures mean.

In particular, how can I relate these numbers to the orientation of the length/area/volume of the corresponding mesh components ? How can I retrieve the notion of "relative orientation of a face within a cell", with which I am more familiar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's a question you really ought to ask Matt Knepley on the PETSc mailing lists. But I think you're on the wrong track: The cone you're talking about is simply one in the graph that connects the different pieces of a DMPLEX. It has no geometric meaning that would relate to length/area/volume.

Comment: After reading similar posts on the PETSc mailing list, I have come to the same conclusion as you : these orientations do not have the meaning I gave them.